# RNRF and displaying a scene based on redux store state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I've got a app that has a collection of scenes, and make many calls to a remote server that because they control hardware can take quite a while.  In my redux store I have a variable that represents if there are any requests inflight.

What I'm trying to achieve is having a spinner or loading scene defined in a single place, and having automatically show dependent on the state of variable in the redux store.

I think that the answer lies in having a `modal` scene for the loading page, but the bit I'm missing is how to have it automatically displayed (and hidden) based from the state in the store.  I don't want to call `Actions.loadingScene()` from all the places that makes the requests.

I've got a reducer in place that see's all the actions (both the application and the RNRF actions), but I couldn't work how what state I had to mutate to get it to display the modal scene.

Any pointers would be great!.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that redux-saga would be the way to solve this, however I ended up making a HOC that adds the spinner, and displays it when required.  It does mean that I have to remember to wrap all scenes with the HOC but that it OK.